# Android Content provider list

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Where can I get the full list of `Content Provider` that Android offers out of the box?
Specifically, I'm looking for a content provider that lists received SMS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The publicly available ones are listed in the android.provider package in the SDK documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/package-summary.html

All other ones are undocumented, presumably for a reason. You are welcome to search the Android source code for those classes which extend `ContentProvider`, perhaps using [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=package%3Aandroid+%22extends+ContentProvider%22&sbtn=Search). And, if you are working on improving the Android firmware, you can also make inquiries on one of the Android [open source project lists](http://source.android.com/discuss) to see how best for you to add in your specific desired capability.

Comment: Some are undocumented since they are were just created for specific purposes, and there is no guarantee that they will always be there - see this blog post by Tim Bray from Google: [Be Careful With Content Providers](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html). He also gives a tip on how to find the others by looking at the source code.

Comment: for those here in 2023, new link to code search with that query: https://cs.android.com/search?q=extends%20ContentProvider&sq=

Answer (score 6):

The content provider for SMS was removed from the SDK in Android 1.5. It was available in the earlier SDKs though.

Use these to get the required URIs

```
Uri.parse("content://sms")
Uri.parsr("content://sms/inbox")
Uri.parsr("content://sms/sent")
etc
```

Keep in mind that since these are undocumented they may change in the future.

For more details look at core/java/android/provider/Telephony.java in the android source code

Comment: Prashast, is this available in SDK 2.2, If not how can I access sms Inbox?

Comment: Unfortunately, these are still undocumented. You still use them on a 2.2 phone though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use adb shell dumpsys > dumpsys.txt and search for "content providers" in that file. From that you can see the list

Answer (score 1):

You can use next line `adb shell dumpsys | grep Provider{`