# Receive notification when a new content provider is installed/registered

Tags: android, installation, listener, android-contentprovider

I have been trying to develop an app that will deal with content providers {contacts, calendar, docs, etc} and their sync options. Although the app works well for existing providers, there might come a time when the authority is not pre-defined. In that case my app can do nothing.

What I need to do is to listen for when a new content provider is installed/registered. For example, if I download Google docs from the market, it registers itself as a provider, so my application should be able to realise that and deal with it accordingly.

Can anyone help with this? I have searched online for two days and unless I'm doing something wrong in the search string, I have no answers thus far. Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

-Sreedevi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect when a new ContentProvider is installed.

What you CAN do is detect when a new package is installed (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) and then use the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)'s [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) interface to list all the `ContentProvider`s the new package has (see the `ProviderInfo[]` array).

Comment: Hi, Femi, thanks for the answer - I found this on StackOverflow as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001590/get-a-list-of-available-content-providers