# Android Content Provider Query by authority substring or by signatures

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to get a list of content providers that exist on a device for a given authority substring.  Each of the providers I will call must have the same signature.

I found that I can get all providers on a device and loop through each of them but I thought there might be a more efficient way. ( [Get a list of available Content Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001590/get-a-list-of-available-content-providers) )

Answer (score 0):

No, the solution outlined in that answer is as good as you are going to get. The concept of "authority substring" is your invention, not a concept intrinsic to Android.

Comment: hmmm, do you see any performance penalties doing things this way?  I will run some tests to see.