# Spotify content providers

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, spotify

I am looking for a way to find the songs the user has stared in spotify.
Does the Spotify app have a public content provider that i can access from my app?

Or is there a general way to find out which open content providers an app has?

Comment: You can get a list of providers; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001590/get-a-list-of-available-content-providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spotify app does not expose a public content provider which can be queried for this type of information. You are better off using libspotify for this in your app, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible if you embed libspotify, and access the users playlists. [libspotify playlist docs](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/group__playlist.html). This seems a little too heavyweight for what you're looking for, though.