# how to read browser history in android phone

Tags: browser-history

I'm working on an app in android that can read/view browser history 
with date and time stamp (optional) 
for a part on my thesis project.

help me :(

I tried this code and it keeps me sending errors

This is on main activity.java

```
package com.example.delli5.bclean;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> titles;
private ArrayList<String> urls;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
private ContentResolver cr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createLists();
}
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getBH();
    showHistoryBookmarks();

}

public void createLists(){
    titles=new ArrayList<String>();
    urls=new ArrayList<String>();
    bitmaps=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

}
public void getBH(){
    Bitmap icon;
    cr=getContentResolver();
    String order=Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE+" DESC";
    String[] projection={Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL,Browser.BookmarkColumns.FAVICON};
    //String selection=projection[0]+"=?";
    //String args[]={"Google"};
    Cursor rows=cr.query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,projection, null,null,order);
    if(rows.getCount()>0){
        while(rows.moveToNext()) {
            //read title
            String title=rows.getString(rows.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
            //read url
            String url=rows.getString(rows.getColumnIndex(projection[1]));
            //read icon
            byte[] bicon=rows.getBlob(rows.getColumnIndex(projection[2]));
            if(bicon!=null){
                //convert blob image data to Bitmap
                icon=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bicon,0,bicon.length);

            }

            else{
                //default icon for history and bookmarks that do not icons
                icon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.noicon);
            }
            //add to lists
            addToList(title,url,icon);
        }
        //close the cursor
        rows.close();
    }


}


public void addToList(String title,String url, Bitmap bitmap){

    titles.add(title);
    urls.add(url);
    bitmaps.add(bitmap);

}


public void showHistoryBookmarks(){
    ListView l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.hb_list);
    if(l!=null){
        if(titles.size()>0){
            ListAdapterModel aa=new ListAdapterModel(this,R.layout.listlayout,R.id.hbtitle,titles,urls,bitmaps);
            l.setAdapter(aa);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "This is no bookmark or history.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}

public void cleanHB(){
    if(Browser.canClearHistory(cr)){
        Browser.clearHistory(cr); //clear history data
        createLists(); //recreate the lists
        onResume(); //update the list
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_clean)
    {
        cleanHB();

    }
    return false;
}


}
}
}
```

and this is on listadaptermodel.java

```
package com.example.delli5.bclean;

/**
 * Created by delli5 on 1/9/2016.
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapterModel {
extends ArrayAdapter<String>

{
    int groupid;
    ArrayList<String> titles;
    ArrayList<String> urls;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
    Context context;
    String path;

    public ListAdapterModel(Context context, int vg, int id, ArrayList<
    String > titles, ArrayList < String > urls, ArrayList < Bitmap >     bitmaps){
    super(context, vg, id, titles);
    this.context = context;
    groupid = vg;
    this.titles = titles;
    this.urls = urls;
    this.bitmaps = bitmaps;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View itemView = inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position));
    TextView textTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hbtitle);
    String title = titles.get(position);
    textTitle.setText(title);
    TextView textURL = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hburl);
    String url = urls.get(position);
    textURL.setText(url);
    //make the url clickable
    Linkify.addLinks(textURL, Linkify.ALL);
    return itemView;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. Did you find the solution? If so, then please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
public class TaskReadHistoric extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

static final String className = "TaskReadHistoric"; 

Context context;

String idAparelho;

// String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
// String brand = Build.BRAND;
// String product = Build.PRODUCT;
// String model = Build.MODEL;

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040445/android-browser-bookmarks-uri-does-not-work-on-all-devices-how-to-find-out-the

public TaskReadHistoric(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

    Preferences pref = new Preferences(context);

    idAparelho = pref.get(Preferences.idAparelho);

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {

        if (Functions.ConnectedInternet(context)) {

        } else {
            return null;
        }

        browserHistoryDOM();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //App.makeLog(e);
        App.makeLog(e, className, "doInBackground", "erro genérico");
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    // new TaskReadHistoric(context).execute();
}

private void browserHistoryDOM() {

    try {
        Cursor mCur = this.context.getContentResolver().query(
                Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null,
                null, null);

        mCur.moveToFirst();

        if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?([^.]+\\.[^.]+)");

            while (!mCur.isAfterLast()) {

                Historico historico = new Historico();

                long callDate = 0;

                try {
                    callDate = Long.parseLong(mCur.getString(3));
                    historico.timestamp = String.valueOf(callDate);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    App.makeLog(e, className, "browserHistoryDOM", "erro ao converter data do histórico");
                }

                if (callDate == 0) {

                    historico.datetime = "Sem registro";

                } else {

                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(callDate);
                    historico.datetime = dateFormat.format(calendar
                            .getTime());

                }

                historico.url = mCur.getString(1);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(new URI(historico.url).getHost());

                if (m.matches()) {
                    historico.titulo = m.group(1);
                }

                if (historico.titulo != null) {
                    historico.titulo = historico.titulo.replace("#", " - ");
                }
                if (historico.url != null) {
                    historico.url = historico.url.replace("#", "-|-|-|-");
                    historico.url = historico.url.replace("&", "|||||||");
                }
                if (historico.datetime != null) {
                    historico.datetime = historico.datetime.replace("#",
                            " - ");
                }

                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

                builder.scheme("http")
                        .authority(Server.Ip)
                        .appendPath("get.php")
                        .appendQueryParameter("action", "setHistorico")
                        .appendQueryParameter("datetime",
                                historico.datetime)
                        .appendQueryParameter("titulo",
                                historico.titulo)
                        .appendQueryParameter("timestamp",
                                historico.timestamp)
                        .appendQueryParameter("url",
                                historico.url)
                        .appendQueryParameter("data", historico.datetime)
                        .appendQueryParameter(Preferences.idAparelho,
                                this.idAparelho);

                String url = builder.build().toString();

                url = url.replace("%40", "@");
                url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
                url = url.replace("%3A", ":");
                url = url.replace("%2F", "/");

                String result = JsonHttp.Execute(url);
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        mCur.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        App.makeLog(e, className, "browserHistoryDOM", "erro generico");

    }
}
```

}