# Authority for the image content provide

Tags: android, provider

Authority for the image content provider.Where can I find the list of all the Authority provided by the android frame work.

vikas bisla

Comment: Already asked/answered. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187541/android-content-provider-list

Comment: Thanks zelimir, i writing sync adaptor for images but not able to find the authority for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

In fact it is

```
content://media/external/images/media
```

so extracting the authority from that gives

```
"media"
```

as the authority. It is the same as the

```
MediaStore.AUTHORITY
```

Comment: When i use Media as authority it works but when MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is used as authority its says sync is not facing problem it will be back shortly.And logs says provider needs a label for authority.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have not understood you correctly. When using ContentProvider I use URL of the table I want access. So, the one I gave you gives you access to pictures on SD card.