# Android system intern Content Providers and their query()-method

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

As far as I know, a ContentProvider has to extend the abstract class ContentProvider and implement a few basic methods, including the query()-method ([Content Provider, Android Official](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)).
I found this question [Android Content provider list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187541/android-content-provider-list) on stackoverflow and one of the answers presents the following site as a list of Content Providers in Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/package-summary.html

But: These classes do not extend ContentProvider and they do not implement said query()-method.
Why do they not extend the ContentProvider-class and what is that class for, if not to be extended by these classes?

Comment: The official ContentProvider guide you linked to has an explanation for those classes http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContractClass

Comment: So what you're saying is that the mentioned classes are not the provider-classes, but the contract classes?

Comment: Yes, the actual providers implementations are in `platform/packages/providers/` in the android source code. For example the calendar provider https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/CalendarProvider/+/android-5.0.2_r1/src/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me a lot! I was confused, as everyone already called the classes provider-classes and they were in the directory as well!